# Array for TotalList argument of Range.Subtotal Method

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use a variable for the TotalList argument but getting a

> Run-time error '1004' Subtotal method of range class failed

Microsoft [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-subtotal-method-excel) isn't helping. The following works when it's hard coded.

```
   .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRow, c - 1)).Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, _
        TotalList:=Array(3, 4, 5, 6), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
```

but my requirements isn't always

> 3,4,5,6

It depends on `accts.count`.

I tried cheating by using a string mimicking the numbers.

```
    For i = 4 To accts.Count - 1 + 2
        arr = arr & ", " & i
    Next
    arr = "3" & arr
```

No go. Then I tried using an array.

```
ReDim arr(0 To 0)
For i = 3 To accts.Count - 1 + 2
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To UBound(arr) + 1)
    arr(UBound(arr) - 1) = i
Next
```

Still failed. Please help.

Comment: Did you try with a 1-based array? Also why do you `ReDim(0 To 0)` and then `ReDim Preserve` if you know from the start how many elements you're going to need? `Dim arr(1 To accts.Count)`

Comment: `'Dim arr(1 To accts.Count)` is giving me `compile error: constant expression required`

Comment: You need to dim the array as empty `Dim arr() as variant` then redim `Redim arr(1 to accts.Count)`

Comment: Gah, that's what I get for coding in SO comments lol thanks @ScottCraner

Comment: Still getting runtime error 1004.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you are leaving an empty at the end of your array.  Plug this loop in and see if it works

```
Dim arr() as variant
ReDim arr(0 To accts.Count-3)
    For i = 3 To accts.Count
        arr(i-3) = i
    Next
```

Comment: `debug.print` did not show an empty in my original code but yours worked with some modification. Thank you.